# POSTGIS inserts become slow after some time

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, postgis, psycopg2

I have a location table with following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE location  
        (  
          id BIGINT,  
          location GEOMETRY,  
          CONSTRAINT location_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, location),  
          CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_geom CHECK (st_ndims(location) = 2),  
          CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_geom CHECK (geometrytype(location) = 'POINT'::TEXT OR location IS NULL),  
          CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_geom CHECK (st_srid(location) = 4326)  
        )  
   WITH (  
          OIDS=FALSE  
         );  

    CREATE INDEX location_geom_gist  ON location  
     USING 
     GIST (location);
```

I run the following query to insert data:

```
def insert_location_data(msisdn, lat, lon):  
    if not (lat and lon):      
            return  
    query = "INSERT INTO location (id, location) VALUES ('%s', ST_GeomFromText('POINT(%s %s)', 4326))"%(str(id), str(lat), str(lon))  
    try:  
        cur = get_cursor()  
        cur.execute(query)  
        conn.commit()  
    except:  
        tb = traceback.format_exc()  
        Logger.get_logger().error("Error while inserting location in sql: %s", str(tb))  
        return False  
    return True
```

I run this block of code 10,000,000 times in a loop but somewhere after 1 million inserts the inserting speed drops drastically. The speed returns to normal when I restart the script but it again drops around a million documents and the same trend continues. I cannot figure out why?
Any help.

Comment: Use extended insert statements. prepare query in loop and then send it to PostgreSQL

Comment: There is a guide here for bulk data loading on postgres: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html

Comment: But why is the scenario happening. The query is fast initially but with time the speed is decreasing. The database size is not the issue since restarting the script reverts the speed to maximum.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few tips.

- Watch out for `str(id)`, which would always return a string `'<built-in function id>'`, since `id` is not shown to be a variable in the question, and is a built-in [`id()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id).
- The correct axis order for PostGIS is (X Y) or (lon lat).
- [There are more efficient ways to insert points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58630/1872).
- [Don't format a string to insert](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters)

This is how to insert one point:

```
cur.execute(
    "INSERT INTO location (id, location) "
    "VALUES (%s, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s, %s), 4326))",
    (msisdn, lon, lat))
```

And see [`executemany`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany) if you want to insert more records at a time, where you would prepare a list of parameters to insert (i.e. `[(msisdn, lon, lat), (msisdn, lon, lat), ..., (msisdn, lon, lat)]`).

Comment: Can you tell me why the inserts are becoming slow after a little time

Comment: @ArijitBasu I can't reproduce that behaviour; I only get *O(n)* (or linear).